# Retrieving data in multiple formats from Excel with Python

Tags: python, vba, excel

**Scenario:** I have an excel file that contains some data in the first sheet. That data can be simple strings on a cell or CheckBoxes (marked or not).

**Data example:**

```
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| item1   | 2004  |                  |      |                  |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| value x | rfd   | checkbox for rfd |  nfd | checkbox for nfd |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
| ident   | test7 | call3            |      |                  |
+---------+-------+------------------+------+------------------+
```

Where "checkbox for rfd" and "checkbox for nfd" are normal checkboxes.

**Objective:** I want to retrieve all that information with python.

**Issue:** I did not find many ways to do this: the only viable things I found was to either use a module (such as win32com) to rum the VBA instance and get the data there. Another was to just open a file, run the VBA subs, then import that to python. 
This works, but it is unnefective for 2 reasons: 1 - this requires me to do a previous VBA manipulation, and since I am trying to automate this process, it is not very smart. 2 - The excel file I am reading is a complete mess, and the checkboxes are all over the place, sometimes duplicated with no reason (that is not something I can fix before hand, since there is a considerable number of files and each of them varies in a different way).

**Question:** Is there a better / more efficient way to do this (particularly directly with python?

**VBA subs:**

```vba
Option Explicit

Sub getControlValues() 'This retrieves the names, values and locations of all objects in the Worksheet

    Dim objx As Object
    Dim cb As Shape
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    'Loop Through ActiveX Checkboxes
    For Each objx In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).OLEObjects
        If objx.Object.Value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = "X"
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = objx.Name
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = objx.BottomRightCell.Address()
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = objx.BottomRightCell.Column
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 5).Value = objx.BottomRightCell.Row

        ElseIf objx.Object.Value = False Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = objx.Name
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = objx.BottomRightCell.Address()
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = objx.BottomRightCell.Column
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 5).Value = objx.BottomRightCell.Row
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next objx

    'Loop through Form Checkboxes
    For Each cb In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes
        If cb.Type = msoFormControl Then
            If cb.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
                If cb.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = "X"
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = cb.Name
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Address()
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Column
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 5).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Row
                ElseIf cb.ControlFormat.Value = xlOff Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 2).Value = cb.Name
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 3).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Address()
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 4).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Column
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(i, 5).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Row
                End If
            i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cb

End Sub

Sub getNormalData() 'This will get all non-object values from the sheet and past the checkbox values into final output

    Dim array_test As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, a As Long

    array_test = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j) = array_test(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    For a = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(a, 1).Value <> "" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(a, 5).Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(a, 4).Value) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(a, 1).Value
        End If
    Next a

End Sub
```

**Python miniscript to retrieve that data:**

```python
import xlrd

db1 = pd.DataFrame()

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Users\\DGMS89\\Downloads\\TEMPLATE.XLSM")

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(2)
```

Comment: Are your checkboxes linked to specific cells in the worksheet? (Can you change the workbook to link each checkbox to a different cell?)

Comment: @PeterT Unfortunately, no. They are not linked and since the files are a mess, I could find no way to viably standardize and link each to a specific cell.

Comment: Have you looked at `pyxll`?  It looks like you can access the COM model (as you mention above) without running the VBA script. This [example](https://www.pyxll.com/docs/examples/automation.html) shows accessing a checkbox.

Comment: You could read the XML of the Excel file instead of opening the file with VBA, this may be faster too. Try writing in memory to Python, rather than to a file, memory ops will be faster than opening/writing to an excel file.